# Asserting a property has been set in a mocked class

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, justmock

I'm using the `MockingContainer<T>` to automatically set up my dependencies. How do I assert that a property on one of those dependencies gets set?

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    //arrange
    _baseUrl = "http://baseUrl";
    _container = new MockingContainer<ApiInteractionService>();
    _container.Arrange<IConfigService>(m => m.BaseUrl).Returns(_baseUrl);
    _uut = _container.Instance;
}
```

The following fails with 0 calls, which makes sense since I believe it's looking at the Getter, not the Setter. So how do I assert that the Setter was called by the unit under test?

```
[Test]
public void BaseUrlSet()
{
    //act
    var _ = _uut.MakeRequest((InitialRequest) Arg.AnyObject);

    //assert     
    _container.Assert<IRestService>(m => m.BaseUrl, Occurs.Once());
}
```

Per the documentation (located at [JustMock Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/justmock/introduction.html) for anyone who isn't familiar but wishes to try assisting) it appears I should be using `Mock.ArrangeSet(lambda)`, however I cannot seem to figure out how to get that syntax to work in relation to `MockingContainer<T>`.

If worse comes to worse, I can just NOT use `MockingContainer<T>`, but I'd prefer to not have to refactor my test suite just to accommodate one specific unit test.

---

Not that it's really relevant to the question, but in the off chance anyone needs it, here is a stub of `ApiInteractionService`

```
public ApiInteractionService(IRestService restService, IConfigService configService)
{
    _restService = restService;
    _restService.BaseUrl = configService.BaseUrl;
}

public string MakeRequest(InitialRequest initialRequest)
{
    return _restService.Post(initialRequest);
}
```

Comment: Why not `_container.Assert<IRestService>(m => m.BaseUrl == _baseUrl);`?

Comment: @Fabio that's not valid code `Telerik.JustMock.Core.MockException: 'The expression does not represent a method call, property access, new expression or a delegate invocation.'` Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply assert that `BaseUrl` has the correct value at the end of the test?

```
var baseUrl = _container.Get<IRestService>().BaseUrl;
Assert.AreEqual(baseUrl, _baseUrl);
```

As suggested in the comments, `_container.Assert<IRestService>(m => m.BaseUrl == _baseUrl)` will not work. `MockingContainer<T>.Assert` asserts an expectation, it's not just asserting truth like regular asserts. The correct syntax would have been:

```
_container.AssertSet<IRestService>(restService => restService.BaseUrl = _baseUrl, Occurs.Once());
```

but, oddly, there is no AssertSet method on the container.